# How to get loop width and length in polly schedule_node

Tags: c++, llvm, isl

gays,How to get loop width and length by using isl::schedule_node in polly/lib/transform/ScheduleOptimizer,i want to get the number to calculatethe tile size

The structure of schedule_node is a bit complicated, I have been trying for a long time and there are always mistakes

i tought length may Node.get_schedule_depth(),but i don't know how to get width

Comment: Have you tried an oracle attack yet? Make some code with width x and see which fields have x as value.